# Calling Rscript within Airflow always throws an error when the function uses /tmp/dir/

Tags: r, airflow

When trying to call an R script using Airflow, if a function uses /tmp, it throws error permission denied. The line below shows the error with `processx`, but it also has happened with `readxl::read_xlsx()` and other functions.

```
 ! cannot start processx process '/tmp/Rtmp3X4GAq/file2615c62ec5483.sh' (system error 13, Permission denied) @unix/processx.c:611 (processx_exec)
```

I have searched for a solution, but so far no luck.